# If a program contains the following code, it may crash. Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

```
int *x;
{
    int y;
    x = &y;  
} 
*x = 5;
```

I think the problem is that x = &y should be changed to x = y. However, I still don't know why it would crash?

Comment: The variable `x` points to goes out of scope when the the program exits the inner scope where `y` is defined.

Comment: `y` is out of scope when its old location is changed.  So it is absolutely UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR and can do anything.  In practice you'll need some extra complications to make that crash.

Comment: **Every** introductory book on C++ explains object lifetimes. You should read [at least one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of `int y` ends at the `}` token.  Since the pointer `x` was pointing at `y`, we now call `x` a "dangling pointer".  Dereferencing a dangling pointer using `*x` is undefined behavior, which might cause a crash or other nasty things, if you're lucky.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is assigned address of `y` on line 5. On line 6 `y` is destroyed. On line 7 you trying to write in variable, which address contained in `x`. Which was destroyed. So you are trying to write into non-existing variable, which leads to undefined behavior.